# jQuery Trigger event fires multiple times

Tags: jquery, triggers, lightbox, autoload

I'm trying to get a jQuery lightbox to load up when a page loads. I got half way there. The lightbox opens when the page loads but then proceeds to open the link in the same window as a full page. How do I get it to stop at this point before loading the link in a separate window.

jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("a.greybox").bind("click", openbox);
  $("a.greybox").trigger('click', openbox);

  function openbox(){
    var t = this.title || $(this).text() || this.href;
    GB_show(t,this.href,340,220);
  }
})
```

HTML:

```
<a href="http://google.com/" title="Google" class="greybox">Launch Google</a>
```

Comment: The second parameter of jQuery's `trigger()` method is meant for passing extra parameters to the event. I have no idea why you are passing your  `openbox` function to the `trigger()` method.

Comment: your right, not needed. But I still cant find a solution that works.

Comment: are you sure you don't have any other `a.greybox` element on the HTML?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you include the line:

```
return false;
```

in your function. That will stop the links original behaviour from firing.

Comment: im sure this would work, im finding its a bug with the emulator.

Answer (score 1):

```
function openbox(evt){
    evt.preventDefault(); // <<-- Add this
    var t = this.title || $(this).text() || this.href; 
    GB_show(t,this.href,340,220);}
}
```